# R: How do transpose value into column but two columns' values?

Tags: r

I am trying to change this table to

```r
ID       Disease1   disease2
1        CVD        HBP
2        CVD        NA
3        HBP        Asthma
4        NA         NA
5        Asthma     CVD
6        CVD        NA
7        HBP        NA
```

this table

```r
ID       CVD   HBP    Asthma    Total
1        1     1      0          2
2        1     0      0          1
3        0     1      1          2
4        0     0      0          0
5        1     0      1          2
6        1     0      0          1
7        0     1      0          1
```

How should I code this? I knew how to transpose one column value section to binary but not as two (because survey allows to select more than 1 value, so the dataset has disease 1, 2, 3.... like this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>%
  reshape2::recast(ID~value, id.var = 'ID', fun.aggregate = length) %>%
  select(-`NA`) %>%
  mutate(Total = rowSums(across(-ID)))

  ID Asthma CVD HBP Total
1  1      0   1   1     2
2  2      0   1   0     1
3  3      1   0   1     2
4  4      0   0   0     0
5  5      1   1   0     2
6  6      0   1   0     1
7  7      0   0   1     1
```

Comment: How do I select specific columns if the disease 1 and 2 are partial column of bigger dataset? I tried (ID~disease1+disease2.. but didn't work.

Comment: @YsabelleBoo I never used `disease` anywhere. So you should not. Look at the formula. All the disease names have been colapsed into a column known as variable. And the answer does not contain disease. Thus I do not have them. Even in your large dataset, run the exact same code

Comment: @YsabelleBoo there is no shortcut for that. well you will have to use `pivot_longer` then `filter` then `pivot_wider`. `recast` is just a `pivot_longer` and  `pivot_wider` in one line

Comment: @YsabelleBoo or just use the code the way it is, but inside `select` include only the columns you are interested in

Answer (score 1):

We may do this in `base R` with `table` and `addmargins`

```
cbind(df1['ID'], as.data.frame.matrix(addmargins(table(rep(df1$ID,
        2), unlist(df1[-1])), 2)))
  ID Asthma CVD HBP Sum
1  1      0   1   1   2
2  2      0   1   0   1
3  3      1   0   1   2
4  4      0   0   0   0
5  5      1   1   0   2
6  6      0   1   0   1
7  7      0   0   1   1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:7, Disease1 = c("CVD", "CVD", "HBP", NA, 
"Asthma", "CVD", "HBP"), disease2 = c("HBP", NA, "Asthma", NA, 
"CVD", NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```